# How to stop infinity printing?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I was trying to build a clock in which I want to show after adding time zone then it show time in running. But the problem is that it is getting printed on multiple times. I want to print it once and keep changing on basis of there timing.

[image]

see in the picture time is changing but It is getting printed multiple times.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="./clock.html">Clock</a>
        <a href="./Stopwatch.html">Stopwatch</a>
    </div>
    <div id="printword"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <input class="search-input" type="text" id="inp" placeholder="Search here..." />
        <input type="button" onclick="handleChange()" value="Submit">
        <div class="suggestions">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        /*start*/
        const countries = [{
            name: "Etc/GMT-12"
        }, {
            name: "Etc/GMT-11"
        }, {
            name: "Pacific/Midway"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-10:00",
            name: "America/Adak"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-09:00",
            name: "America/Anchorage"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-09:00",
            name: "Pacific/Gambier"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-08:00",
            name: "America/Dawson_Creek"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-08:00",
            name: "America/Ensenada"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-08:00",
            name: "America/Los_Angeles"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-07:00",
            name: "America/Chihuahua"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-07:00",
            name: "America/Denver"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-06:00",
            name: "America/Belize"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT-06:00",
            name: "America/Cancun"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+02:00",
            name: "Asia/Jerusalem"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+03:00",
            name: "Africa/Addis_Ababa"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+03:00",
            name: "Asia/Riyadh89"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+03:00",
            name: "Europe/Minsk"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+03:30",
            name: "Asia/Tehran"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+04:00",
            name: "Asia/Dubai"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+04:00",
            name: "Asia/Yerevan"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+04:00",
            name: "Europe/Moscow"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+04:30",
            name: "Asia/Kabul"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+05:00",
            name: "Asia/Tashkent"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+05:30",
            name: "Asia/Kolkata"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+05:45",
            name: "Asia/Katmandu"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+06:00",
            name: "Asia/Dhaka"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+06:00",
            name: "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+06:30",
            name: "Asia/Rangoon"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+07:00",
            name: "Asia/Bangkok"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+07:00",
            name: "Asia/Novosibirsk"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+08:00",
            name: "Etc/GMT+8"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+08:00",
            name: "Asia/Hong_Kong"
        }, {
            "ofset": "GMT+08:00",
            name: "Asia/Krasnoyarsk"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+08:00",
            name: "Australia/Perth"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+08:45",
            name: "Australia/Eucla"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+09:00",
            name: "Asia/Irkutsk"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+09:00",
            name: "Asia/Seoul"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+09:00",
            name: "Asia/Tokyo"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+09:30",
            name: "Australia/Adelaide"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+09:30",
            name: "Australia/Darwin"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+09:30",
            name: "Pacific/Marquesas"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+10:00",
            name: "Etc/GMT+10"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+10:00",
            name: "Australia/Brisbane"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+10:00",
            name: "Australia/Hobart"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+10:00",
            name: "Asia/Yakutsk"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+10:30",
            name: "Australia/Lord_Howe"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+11:00",
            name: "Asia/Vladivostok"
        }, {
            "offset": "GMT+11:30",
            name: "Pacific/Norfolk"
        }, {
            name: "Etc/GMT+12"
        }, {
            name: "Asia/Anadyr"
        }, {
            name: "Asia/Magadan"
        }, {
            name: "Pacific/Auckland"
        }, {
            name: "Pacific/Chatham"
        }, {
            name: "Pacific/Tongatapu"
        }, {
            name: "Pacific/Kiritimati"
        }];

        const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
        const suggestionsPanel = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

        searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                const input = searchInput.value;
                suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
                const suggestions = countries.filter(function(country) {
                    return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(input);
                });
                suggestions.forEach(function(suggested) {
                    const div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = suggested.name;
                    div.addEventListener("click", () => searchInput.value = div.innerText);
                    suggestionsPanel.appendChild(div);
                });
                if (input === '') {
                    suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
                }
            })
            /* end*/
        let event = new Date();
        console.log(event.getHours());
        document.getElementById("printword").innerHTML = event;
        let history = "";

        function handleChange() {
            // let et;
            let CollectTimezone = [];
            let InpValue = document.getElementById("inp").value;
            CollectTimezone.push(InpValue);
            for (let i = 0; i < CollectTimezone.length; i++) {
                console.log(CollectTimezone[i]); {
                    currTime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
                        timeZone: CollectTimezone[i]
                    });
                    console.log(currTime);
                    // let currDate = et.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
                    //     timeZone: CollectTimezone[i]
                    // });
                    history += currTime + " " + CollectTimezone[i] + "</br>";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("printword").innerHTML = history;
            displayCurr();
        }

        function displayCurr() {
            refresh = 1000;
            mytime = setTimeout('handleChange()', refresh);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything that would cause an infinite loop, and there's no "printing" at all, so, not sure what the issue could be

Comment: oh, wait, I see ... `displayCurr` calls `handleChange` which calls `displayCurr` which calls `handleChange` ... yeah, just don't do that - you need to figure out your logic, I can't do it for you

Comment: I used history+=currTime in order to store another timezone so that on adding another timezone it print in stack all the timezone whatever I had added in it. Once disabling displayCurr() function you can see the impact. And now in current code we loose the previous timezone on adding new one. @obsidian-age

Answer (score 1):

Although you're setting the `printword` `.innerHTML` *equal* to `history`, you're *appending* to `history` itself inside of your loop. Instead of `history += currTime...` just use `history = currTime...`:

**Note**: Console logs removed for clarity.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="./clock.html">Clock</a>
    <a href="./Stopwatch.html">Stopwatch</a>
  </div>
  <div id="printword"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <input class="search-input" type="text" id="inp" placeholder="Search here..." />
    <input type="button" onclick="handleChange()" value="Submit">
    <div class="suggestions">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    /*start*/
    const countries = [{
      name: "Etc/GMT-12"
    }, {
      name: "Etc/GMT-11"
    }, {
      name: "Pacific/Midway"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-10:00",
      name: "America/Adak"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-09:00",
      name: "America/Anchorage"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-09:00",
      name: "Pacific/Gambier"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-08:00",
      name: "America/Dawson_Creek"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-08:00",
      name: "America/Ensenada"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-08:00",
      name: "America/Los_Angeles"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-07:00",
      name: "America/Chihuahua"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-07:00",
      name: "America/Denver"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-06:00",
      name: "America/Belize"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT-06:00",
      name: "America/Cancun"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+02:00",
      name: "Asia/Jerusalem"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+03:00",
      name: "Africa/Addis_Ababa"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+03:00",
      name: "Asia/Riyadh89"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+03:00",
      name: "Europe/Minsk"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+03:30",
      name: "Asia/Tehran"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+04:00",
      name: "Asia/Dubai"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+04:00",
      name: "Asia/Yerevan"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+04:00",
      name: "Europe/Moscow"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+04:30",
      name: "Asia/Kabul"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+05:00",
      name: "Asia/Tashkent"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+05:30",
      name: "Asia/Kolkata"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+05:45",
      name: "Asia/Katmandu"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+06:00",
      name: "Asia/Dhaka"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+06:00",
      name: "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+06:30",
      name: "Asia/Rangoon"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+07:00",
      name: "Asia/Bangkok"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+07:00",
      name: "Asia/Novosibirsk"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+08:00",
      name: "Etc/GMT+8"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+08:00",
      name: "Asia/Hong_Kong"
    }, {
      "ofset": "GMT+08:00",
      name: "Asia/Krasnoyarsk"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+08:00",
      name: "Australia/Perth"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+08:45",
      name: "Australia/Eucla"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+09:00",
      name: "Asia/Irkutsk"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+09:00",
      name: "Asia/Seoul"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+09:00",
      name: "Asia/Tokyo"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+09:30",
      name: "Australia/Adelaide"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+09:30",
      name: "Australia/Darwin"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+09:30",
      name: "Pacific/Marquesas"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+10:00",
      name: "Etc/GMT+10"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+10:00",
      name: "Australia/Brisbane"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+10:00",
      name: "Australia/Hobart"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+10:00",
      name: "Asia/Yakutsk"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+10:30",
      name: "Australia/Lord_Howe"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+11:00",
      name: "Asia/Vladivostok"
    }, {
      "offset": "GMT+11:30",
      name: "Pacific/Norfolk"
    }, {
      name: "Etc/GMT+12"
    }, {
      name: "Asia/Anadyr"
    }, {
      name: "Asia/Magadan"
    }, {
      name: "Pacific/Auckland"
    }, {
      name: "Pacific/Chatham"
    }, {
      name: "Pacific/Tongatapu"
    }, {
      name: "Pacific/Kiritimati"
    }];

    const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
    const suggestionsPanel = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

    searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      const input = searchInput.value;
      suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
      const suggestions = countries.filter(function(country) {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(input);
      });
      suggestions.forEach(function(suggested) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = suggested.name;
        div.addEventListener("click", () => searchInput.value = div.innerText);
        suggestionsPanel.appendChild(div);
      });
      if (input === '') {
        suggestionsPanel.innerHTML = '';
      }
    })
    /* end*/
    let event = new Date();
    document.getElementById("printword").innerHTML = event;
    let history = "";

    function handleChange() {
      // let et;
      let CollectTimezone = [];
      let InpValue = document.getElementById("inp").value;
      CollectTimezone.push(InpValue);
      for (let i = 0; i < CollectTimezone.length; i++) {
        currTime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
          timeZone: CollectTimezone[i]
        });
        // let currDate = et.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
        //     timeZone: CollectTimezone[i]
        // });
        history = currTime + " " + CollectTimezone[i] + "</br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("printword").innerHTML = history;
      displayCurr();
    }

    function displayCurr() {
      refresh = 1000;
      mytime = setTimeout('handleChange()', refresh);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used history+=currTime  in order to store another timezone  so that on adding another timezone it print in stack all the timezone whatever I had added in it.  Once  disabling  displayCurr() function you can see the impact. And now in current code we loose the previous timezone on adding new one.